# Why do we need to mention the loss function in Keras load_model function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I created a Keras model using a custom loss function and saved it. When I reload the trained model using Keras `load_model()` function to make the prediction, I had to pass the custom loss function to `custom_objects` argument:

```
new_model=load_model('yolo_1.model',custom_objects={'custom_loss':custom_loss})
```

My question is, why we have to mention the custom loss function in `load_model()`? I think loss function is not needed in prediction process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `include_optimizer` argument of `save` method is by default set to `True`. Therefore, the optimizer as well as the loss function will be saved and as a result they will be loaded when you use `load_model` function.

However, if you only want to use your model for prediction then you would not need to save the optimizer and therefore set the `include_optimizer` to `False` when saving the model:

```
model.save('my_model.h5', include_optimizer=False)
```

This way the optimizer and the loss function used will not be saved and therefore you would not need to specify the custom loss function you have used when loading the model.